# Pattern of decoding instruction

Tags: parallel-processing, x86, cpu-architecture, pipelining

I am analyzing [Agner Fog's](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) 
["Optimizing subroutines in assembly language: An optimization guide for x86 platforms"](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf). 
Especially I am trying to understand chapter 12.7. And there is an issue I can not understand. The author writes:

> Instruction decoding in the PM processor follows the 4-1-1 pattern. The pattern of (fused)
>   μops for each instruction in the loop in example 12.6b is 2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1. This is not optimal,
>   and it will take 6 clock cycles to decode. This is more than the retirement time, so we can
>   conclude that instruction decoding is the bottleneck in example 12.6b. The total execution
>   time is 6 clock cycles per iteration or 3 clock cycles per calculated Y[i] value.

1. What does it mean that instruction decoding follows the 4-1-1 pattern and how to know it?
2. Pattern for loop is 2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1. Ok, but why it takes 6 cycle to decode I don't know. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The CPU's frontend can decode multiple (macro) instructions in one clock cycle. Each macro instruction decodes to 1 or more micro-ops (μops). What the 4-1-1 pattern means is that the first parallel decoder can handle a complex instruction that decodes to up to 4 μops. But the second and third parallel decoders can only handle instructions that decode to 1 μop each (if not satisfied, they don't consume the instruction).
2. The 5 instructions that decode to 2 μops will must be consumed by the first decoder, then the tail allows some parallelism.

   ```
   2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 (Macro-instruction stream, μops per instruction)
   ^ x x
   4 1 1  (Decode cycle 0)

   . 2 2 2 2 1 1 1
     ^ x x
     4 1 1  (Decode cycle 1)

   . . 2 2 2 1 1 1
       ^ x x
       4 1 1  (Decode cycle 2)

   . . . 2 2 1 1 1
         ^ x x
         4 1 1  (Decode cycle 3)

   . . . . 2 1 1 1
           ^ ^ ^
           4 1 1  (Decode cycle 4)

   . . . . . . . 1
                 ^ x x
                 4 1 1  (Decode cycle 5)

   . . . . . . . . (Instruction stream fully consumed)
   ```

Comment: thanks :) 
How to know pattern for patricular processor?

Comment: Agner's guide should have some information. If not, search CPU architecture articles on Ars Technica

Comment: For some recent Intel processors (Skylake and Haswell so far) - you can find a detailed investigation of the instruction fetch behavior [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39940932/149138).