# Pow function returning wrong result

Tags: c, math, pow, calculation

When I use the `pow()` function, sometimes the results are off by one.  For example, this code produces 124, but I know that 5³ should be 125.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    int i = pow(5, 3);
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Why is the result wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken Using float pow() for int is rarely predictable.

Comment: Implement a version of `pow` in your program to work with integral input. That will prevent the problems of using floating point math.

Comment: Looks like a perfect opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: If the program is in C please don’t tag C++ since it’s not relevant.

Comment: There must be a duplicate for problems with `(int) pow()`...

Comment: `pow` uses [logarithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072787/why-is-powint-int-so-slow/41078483) to calculate x^y, and log is calculated thanks to series which sometimes gets a bit higher results, sometimes (your case) a bit lower.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I doubt a debugger would help much here. He's already identified the location of the problem, and it's a standard library function, the code of which may not even be available (and it probably wouldn't help much even if it was).

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is that you are mixing integer variables with floating point math. My bet is that the result of `5^3` is something like `124.999999` due to rounding problems and when cast into integer variable get `floor`ed to `124`.

There are 3 ways to deal with this:

1. **more safely mix floating math and integers**

   ```cpp
   int x=5,y=3,z;
   z=floor(pow(x,y)+0.5);
   // or
   z=round(pow(x,y));
   ```

   but using this will always present a possible risk of rounding errors affecting the result especially for higher exponents.
2. **compute on floating variables only**

   so replace `int` with `float` or `double`. This is a bit safer than **#1** but still in some cases is this not usable (depends on the task). and may need occasional `floor,ceil,round` along the way to get the wanted result correctly.
3. **Use integer math only**

   This is the safest way (unless you cross the `int` limit). The `pow` can be computed on integer math relatively easily see:

   - [Power by squaring for negative exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214)

Comment: (1) is safe up to the 53rd power of 2 for IEEE754 `double`, and is an elegant fix. (2) is a bad idea, (3) by far the best, so +2/3.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes and they state the same. But there are tasks where the #1,#2 approaches are enough or even preferred but all depends on the task  and target accuracy

Answer (score 3):

`pow(x, y)` is most likely implemented as `exp(y * log(x))`: modern CPUs can evaluate `exp` and `log` in a couple of flicks of the wrist.

Although adequate for many scientific applications, when truncating the result to an integer, the result can be off for even trivial arguments. That's what is happening here.

Your best bet is to roll your own version of `pow` for integer arguments; i.e. find one from a good library. As a starting point, see [The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int)

Answer (score 2):

Use Float Data Type

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float x=2;
    float y=2;
    float p= pow(x,y);
    printf("%f",p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prefer `double` instead. Notice that before the variables get sent to the functions that use them, they are automatically converted to `double`.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this function instead of `pow`:

```
long long int Pow(long long int base, unsigned int exp)
{
    if (exp > 0)
        return base * Pow(base, exp-1);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It will be  better to use a looping implementation instead of a recursive implementation.

Comment: Hopefully the stack will resist a high exp

Comment: @RSahu: Yes, that's also an option. There are other options as well, even more efficient, which run in `O(log(exp))`, but I figured that this dude's main problem was correctness rather than performance.

Comment: SO has a bunch of implementations already, to calculate int^int

Comment: @ringø: And hopefully the `long long int` will "resist" a high `exp` (in terms of wrap-around). I think, though, that this is not the main issue that this dude's question is all about...

Comment: @goodvibration, performance and stack problems aside, a looping implementation is probably easier to follow for a beginner.

Comment: @RSahu: Yes, that one I do agree with :)

Comment: @ringø: No, with regards to the `long long int` - I do mean in terms of wrap-around. A stack overflow would occur due to the recursive implementation, not due to the type being used.

Comment: Never said that :-) Of course SO would occur due to recursivity.

Comment: @ringø: Ohhhhhh, You used "SO" for this website's name!!! Damn. OK, sorry for the misunderstanding. BTW, still, not sure what the point in that comment. Of course there are plenty of integer solutions here, as in other places (Google, etc).

Comment: Probably the worst `Pow` implementation I've seen in a while.