# what does the variabel in printf do

Tags: c

```
Why didn't this code work after adding "res=pow(arr[i],x)"
```

I want it to print like this
"printf("%d * %d = %d \n",i+1,x,pow(arr[i],x));"
The code doesn't work untill i print like this
"printf("%d * %d = %d \n",i+1,x,res)));"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
int arr[5];            
for(int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
printf("enter the numbers %d\n",i+1);
scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}
int x;
printf("what is power would you like...\n");
scanf(" %d",&x);
printf("The power of the array elements is...\n");
for(int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
printf("%d * %d = %d \n",i+1,x,pow(arr[i],x));
}
return 0;   //  1*2=1*1    ,    3*2=3*3 
}
```

Comment: if i write  int res = pow(arr[i],x) ;   printf("%d * %d = %d \n",i+1,x,res));    it works why?

Comment: `pow()` function returns a double, not an integer. so, you should use %f in your printf for the 3rd value to print.

Answer (score 0):

`pow` returns a double. You need `%lf` format for the third argument or you'll get undefined behaviour trying to format a floating point value with an integer `%d` format (most compilers issue a warning about this BTW).

quickfix

```
printf("%d * %d = %lf \n",i+1,x,pow(arr[i],x));
```

Assigning the result to an integer workarounds the issue. That's why it works then (but sometimes [it leads to rounding errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406858/pow-function-returning-wrong-result) so beware!)

You may have a look at [integer power algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int) instead. `pow` is more suited for floating point operations.

Comment: i don’t get that     ....i need to do this in my code printf("%d * %d = %d \n",i+1,x,pow(arr[i],x)); but it doesn’t work until i do this ...int res=pow(arr[i] , x);    
printf("%d * %d = %d \n",i+1,x,res);......why it dos’t work like i want ?

Comment: see my edit for the formatting error