# SIGSEV on filling matrix in C

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, runtime-error

I am currently working on a simple code that should multiply two matrices between each other but as soon as I tried to create matrices with size more than 4 by 4 I faced with SIGSEV.

```
Matrix* allocate_matrix(size_t N) {
  int i, j;
  size_t MSIZE;
  Matrix* matrix = malloc(sizeof(int*) * (N * SIZE_MULT));
  MSIZE = N * SIZE_MULT;

  if (matrix == NULL) {
    perror("Error on malloc matrix");
    exit(2);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < MSIZE; i++) {
    matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * MSIZE);

    if (matrix[i] == NULL) {
      perror("Error on malloc matrix[i]");

      for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        free(matrix[j]);
      }

      free(matrix);

      exit(2);
    }
  }

  #if DEBUG
  printf("Matrix allocated");
  #endif

  return matrix;
}
```

This is the way i allocate memory Matrix type is defined as int**

```
void fill_matrix(Matrix* m, size_t N) {
  size_t x;
  size_t y;
  size_t MSIZE;
  MSIZE = N * SIZE_MULT;

  for (y = 0; y < MSIZE; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < MSIZE; x++) {
      m[y][x] = rand() % INT_LIMIT;

      #if DEBUG
      /*printf("Generated int: %d on [%ld][%ld]\n\n", m[y][x], y, x);*/
      #endif
    }
  }

  printf("Matrix filled");

  return;
}
```

This is the func of insering numbers into matrix.

Sry guys for a stupid question, but i really have no clue what`s wrong..

The code is working perfectly fine with one of them,e.g I successfully created a matrix 10 by 10, but as soon as the second one appears and has to be filled in it crashes. Guys, i need some hints.

Comment: What is `SIZE_MULT`?

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit machine or a 64-bit machine?  The size 4 suggests that it might be a 32-bit machine and there's a problem somewhere because of that, but I've not yet analyzed the code fully.  It would help if you created an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).  Can you use [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: How is `Matrix` defined? It seems odd to have a function argument `Matrix* m` followed by `m[y][x]`. Does the code compile without warnings?

Comment: Note that it is usually a good idea to end `printf()` format strings with a newline, especially those printing progress information.  That helps ensure the messages are printed in a timely fashion.  Writing to `stderr` instead of `stdout` can be a good idea too (though even then, a newline is helpful).

Comment: 1. SIZE MULT is a const witch is defined as pow(10,3) at the momet
2. i use 64 bit ubuntu linux 20.04
3 typedef int** Matrix; that`s how the matrix type is defined

Comment: Two points: it's bad to use `pow` to obtain an exact integer, and it's not good practice to hide a pointer behind a typedef.

Comment: You have too many levels of `*` in your types. If `Matrix` is `int**`, `Matrix*` is `int***`. But your allocations are just `int**`.

Comment: *SIZE MULT is a const witch is defined as pow(10,3)*?!?  **Never** use a floating-point-based definition for fundamentally integer values.  `pow(10,3)` is likely to return something like `999.9999`, which rounds **down** to `999` when forced into an integral context.

Comment: Yep, thanks @Barmar and others, really appreciate your help, and hints you gave, I really had to much pointers, now it works good.

Comment: @AndrewHenle "pow(10,3) is likely to return something like 999.9999" No, it is unlikely to return anything like that. Rather impossible really.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI *"pow(10,3) is likely to return something like 999.9999" No, it is unlikely to return anything like that. Rather impossible really.* [Oh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406858/pow-function-returning-wrong-result)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have actually tested all possible values of pow(x,y) where x and y are positive integers and the result is less than UINT_MAX with several compilers and libraries and compiler options, and I have never found a result that wasn't an integer. Perhaps I wasn't looking hard enough, because I now see people sometimes complain about such results. Oddly they never specify what compilers and libraries they are using. Perhaps you can help me find the right combination?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Oh, `999` is an `int`, alright.  But if you get that back from `(int) pow(10,3)` when you were expecting `1000` and write your code with the expectation that you allocated 1000 objects when you only allocated 999, your code will likely do things like fail with a `SIGSEGV`....

Comment: @AndrewHenle I never said I looked at `(int) pow(10,3)` or anything like that. Why would I? I looked at `pow(x,y)` not cast to anything.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not hide pointers behind typedefs
2. `***` [pointer usually indicates erratic, bad code](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)
3. Use parameters to pass all sizes. Avoid strange defines all global variables.
4. You can use array pointers
5. Use objects in `sizeof` instead of types
6. Use meaningful names for loop control variables (and all other variables too).

example:

```
void *allocate_matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols) 
{
    int *matrix = malloc(sizeof(*matrix) * rows * cols);
    return matrix;
}

void *fill_matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*matrix)[cols]) 
{
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++) 
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++) 
        {
            matrix[row][col] = rand() % 1000;
        }
    }

    printf("Matrix filled\n");

    return matrix;
}


int main(void)
{
    size_t rows, cols;

    srand(time(NULL));

    rows = rand() % 20;
    cols = rand() % 20;

    int (*matrix)[cols] = allocate_matrix(rows, cols);

    if(matrix)
    {
        fill_matrix(rows, cols, matrix);
        for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++) 
        {
            for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++) 
            {
                printf("% 5d\t", matrix[row][col]);
            }   
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/q6nffGrYx