# pow() function in C problems

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy, pow

I am having some problems with `pow()` function in C. When ever run this code, `153` as input, the sum evaluates to `152`. However if I dont use `pow()` function and instead use a `for` loop to get the value of **N<sup>n</sup>**, the sum evaluates to `153`. Can anyone help please explain me this difference?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int i, n, sum = 0, N, a = 1, j;
    char num[100], x[2] = { 0 };
    printf("Determining an armstrong number\n\n"
           "Enter a number: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(num);
    n = strlen(num);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a = 1;
        x[0] = num[i];
        N = atoi(x);
        /* for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            a *= N;
        */
        sum += pow(N, n);
    }
    n = atoi(num);
    if (sum == n)
        printf("\nIt is an Armstrong number!\n");
    else
        printf("\nIt is not an Armstrong number!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);`--> **UB** `gets`--> **Don't** use it

Comment: Don't use `pow` for integer power calculation.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072787/why-is-powint-int-so-slow about how *pow()* is calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C implementation, including its math library, has a bad implementation of `pow` that returns inaccurate results. (A good `pow` implementation returns an exact result when the mathematical result is exactly representable in the floating-point format.) For example, for `pow(7, 2)`, your `pow` may be returning a value slightly under 49. When this is converted to an `unsigned int` (in the addition to `sum`), it is truncated, resulting in 48.

To work around this defect in your library, do not use `pow` for integer arithmetic. Write your own integer arithmetic to get the result you desire. In some circumstances, using `round(pow(N, n))` may suffice, but there are considerations of the range of values for which this will work (wide integers may be able to represent integers that `double` cannot) and sometimes performance. (Another workaround is to get a better C implementation.)