# How to add 2 to each digit in a 4 digit number in C

Tags: c

I am trying to solve this tutorial practice question that doesn't have an answer that I can check my code against. The goal is to write a program to display numbers whose digits are `2` greater than the corresponding digits of the entered number. So if the number input is `5656` then the output number should be `7878`. I have figured out how to separate each number and add them, but I can't seem to get them to print in a *four-digit* sequence.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int n, one, two, three, four, final;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    one   = (n / 1000);
    n     = (n % 1000) + 2;
    two   = (n / 100) + 2;
    n     = (n % 100) + 2;
    three = (n / 10) + 2;
    n     = (n % 10) + 2;
    four  = (n / 1) + 2;
    n     = (n % 1) + 2;

    final = (one * 1000) + (two * 100) + (three * 10) + four;

    printf("%d", final);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your algorithm is incorrect - you should only be adding the two on the "divide" lines, not the "modulus" ones.

Comment: What do you do for an input like `8989` ?

Comment: can't you just do `final = n + 2222;` ?

Comment: @RingØ Yes any four digit number and the program is supposed to add two to each digit.

Comment: Sander's solution must be the one for you.

Comment: @Alnitak I changed it and it worked for number less than 9. 5696 came out as 7918 so I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: @Exodus5656 you never described the intended output for when a digit is 8 or larger.    What happens if you add 2 to 8?   You get a carry...

Comment: @Exodus5656 i.e. what did you _expect_ the output to be for 5696?   Should it have been 7818 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     int n,a[4], final;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i=3;i>=0;i--)
    {
        a[i]=n%10+2;
        n/=10;
    }
    final = (a[0] * 1000) + (a[1] * 100) + (a[2] * 10) + a[3];
    printf("%d", final);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I use for variable a I create an array?

Comment: Yes [a] is a array of int

Comment: I am lazy to write four div and mod, for four distinct variable :) Good Luck!

Comment: This works perfectly, but arrays and for statements are further in the tutorial. Your code does look a lot better and is shorter than what the answer was.

Answer (score 1):

Below function works with N number of digits.
Idea is to extract each digit from the input number and add its decimal position.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int x, int y)
{
  int res = 1;
  for (;y>0;y--)
  {
    res *=x;
  }
  return res;
}
int main ()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int sum = 0;
    int i=0;
    while(n>0)
    {
       sum += ((n%10) +2)*power(10,i);
       i++;
       n /=10;
    }

    printf("%d", sum);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Ouch, `pow`, [really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072787/why-is-powint-int-so-slow)?

Comment: I should have put in post that arrays and statements are not allowed since they have not been covered. This is really basic stuff. Will learn to edit post.

Comment: In this answer no array is used.

Comment: Well, instead of `int i = 0; … { …something * pow(10, i); … ++i; … }`, why not a simple `int i = 1; … something * i; … i *= 10; … }`?

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:

```
char str[10]; // enough to contain an int as string + 1
char *s = str+sizeof(str); // points to last char + 1
int n;

scanf("%d", &n);
*--s = 0;  // terminate the string

while(n) {
    *--s = (((n % 10)+2)%10) + '0'; // write a char from the end
    n /= 10;
}
printf("%s\n", s);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    int a = 5696;
    //      output is 7818
    // ---------Java-----------
    // --------solution--------



    int first  = a/1000+2;
    
    int b = a%1000;
    int second = b/100+2;
    
    int c = b%100;
    int d = c/10+2;
    int third = d/10;
    
    int e = c%10;
    int fourth = e+2;
    
    String result = Integer.toString(first)+Integer.toString(second)+Integer.toString(third)+Integer.toString(fourth);
            
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Only code answers are generally poor answers. On top of that, the usefulness of a Java version for this question seems questionable. I suggest you to edit your answer in a way highlighting at least the Java peculiars here.